# Unable to use onSnapshot method with a Firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Has Firebase made some changes to their Firestore database? Earlier I could listen to any change in a collection by using (within the useEffect hook in React):

```
db.collection('todos').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
   //code to be executed
})
```

The above would get executed every time there was any change to the collection.

But now when I use the above, I get the error that onSnapsot() is not a function.

How can I listen to a change in Firestore collection. For example every time I make an entry, I want to essentially display the new updated list within my Todo app.

Comment: what is db? it must be a firestore instance.

Comment: Please check which version of the Firebase sdk you're using. Firebase v9 launched less than a month ago and many of the functions have changed to make it tree shakeable

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062206/how-do-i-add-firebase-to-my-react-project?